# Objective-C Forward Method Declaration

Tags: objective-c

I have written a method `formatSearchString` for a class and am trying to call it on a line before it is implemented (shouldn't matter?).  I get this error:

```
Error: Semantic Issue
Use of undeclared identifier 'formatSearchString'
```

I am using XCode 4.6.2

The interface file `FHViewController.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FHViewController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchTerm;
- (NSString *)formatSearchString:(NSString *)userEntry;
@end
```

The implementation file `FHViewController.m`:

```
#import "FHViewController.h"

@interface FHViewController()
- (NSString *)formatSearchString:(NSString *)userEntry;
@end

@implementation FHViewController
@synthesize searchTerm;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSString *formatted = [formatSearchString userEntry:searchTerm];
}

- (NSString *)formatSearchString:(NSString *)userEntry
{
     NSLog(@"User Entry: %@", userEntry);
     return @"Dummy string for now";
}
@end
```

Comment: Why did you add the method declaration to both the .h file and to the class extension in the .m file? Neither is needed. You only want the method declaration in the .h file if the method is used by other classes. And you don't need the forward declaration in the .m file anymore with modern Objective-C.

Comment: You should also likely change that `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`, since that's where `UI*`-based classes are declared. Your project compiles OK now because of the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` that's in your `<Project-name>-Prefix.pch` pre-compiled headers file, but ideally, the class shouldn't have to rely on that.

Comment: All of your suggestions have been implemented and work perfectly.  Thank you.  I am new to objective-c.  The pattern I followed came from (apparently outdated) Apple objective-c API documentation along with posts from this site asking the same question.  My real problem was thinking like a 15-year Java programmer -- not realizing that I needed to explicitly say "self" to call a method on my own class.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *formatted = [formatSearchString userEntry:searchTerm];
```

That line is wrong. Note the difference :

```
NSString *formatted = [self formatSearchString:searchTerm];
```

Comment: How straightforward.  I need to think more about explicitly calling out "self" in Objective-c.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are using formatSearchString as a variable name, not a method name, you need to call formatSearchString on an object:

```
NSString *formattedString = [self formatSearchString:mySearchString];
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a method call in Objective C is `[receiver method: param1 ...]`. So you need to change your code to:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *formatted = [self formatSearchString: searchTerm];
}
```